# How to use Eloquent without lost of performance (51.39%) in Lumen 5.4?

Tags: mysql, performance, laravel, lumen

I am developing a API that should deal with a high perfomant web site.
I was just doing some test in order to compare access to database trough Eloquent versus no Eloquent.

Here is my route that should return all cities from the table cities.

```
$app->get('cities', 'CitiesController@index');
```

Here I have my CitiesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Citie;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return DB::select("SELECT * FROM cities");
        //return Citie::all();
    }
}
```

And that is my Model **Citie**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Citie extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=['id'];
}
```

I just type mysite/cities in the URL and I will get all the the 5565 cities from the table cities.

I am using POSTMAN in order to perform the request and that are the results after 10 tests:

**CitiesController** switched to return `DB::select("SELECT * FROM cities");` **without Eloquent** and time in miliseconds(ms):

```
1975
1698
1809
1817
1918
1841
1897
1689
1854
1958
Av - 1845.6
```

**CitiesController** switched to return `Citie::all();` **with Eloquent** and time in miliseconds(ms):

```
3449
3684
3654
3667
3546
3491
3462
3531
3614
3815
Av - 3591.3
```

It seems that, in my scenario, Eloquent in Lumen is **51.39 %** less performant than if I dont use it.

So, the question is  how could I improve that Eloquent performance to achieve at least **1845.6ms**? Is there something wrong with my code?

example:
[image]

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cities`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `fk_province` INT NOT NULL,
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `geocodeBr` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  `lat` DECIMAL(10,8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `long` DECIMAL(11,8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_city_province_idx` (`fk_province` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_city_province`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_province`)
    REFERENCES `provinces` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: Please show us the SQL generated in each case.  We may be able to recommend what the SQL< should be, then it is a matter of working backwards.  1900 seconds to fetch 5565 rows -- something is wrong with even that!  I would expect under 60 seconds, even in a pathological case.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE cities`.  Do you really need `*`?

Comment: `Do you really need * ?` Not for this moment. But I will. In any case, the point is the difference of 50% in performance between Eloquent and not.

Comment: Are you sure the times were not milliseconds?  Let's see Eloquent's `SELECT`.

Comment: you are right. is ms. but still 50%

Comment: Possibility 1:  The SQL is different.  Possibility 2:  The faster is fetching the entire resultset in a single step; the other is fetching piecemeal.  (I don't know where the setting is for this -- maybe in the connection, maybe in the query.)  Dig deeper.

Comment: Old question, but regarding to what @RickJames says, Eloquent generated query is indeed different, since it also may (or not?) check for `softDeleted` records appending a `WHERE deleted_at = null`. That may not be what is causing the 50% overhead but its something to take in mind

Comment: good to know!!!

Comment: @Frondor - hopefully it is not exactly `= NULL` -- the correct syntax is `IS NULL`.  Anyway, that extra test probably would not cost 50%; however, if the amount of data is a lot, then the network transmission time could be the cost?  How many rows with (versus without) the soft-delete check?